# How to color shapes when i click on button in power point?

Tags: vba, powerpoint, powerpoint-2013

I want to change color for a selected shape. If i click one shape and i click a button i want to change color in red, like in picture but when i press button.

How i create a button i put condition to change color shapes selected?

I tried to change color by pressing another shapes but is not what i want.

Thanks a lot

[image]

Answer (score 0):

OK, so firstly, because you are trying to change the colour of a selected shape, this implies you are in the normal (editing) view and not a slide show. Secondly, ActiveX buttons or shapes with Actions to run macros can only be clicked when in slide show mode. So, the only option you have for a "button" in the normal view is to use the ribbon extensibility features of Office. You need to add the XML for a button to the customUI of your PowerPoint file and create an associated macro for it to run. For example, add this XML to your file using the [CustomUI Editor](http://openxmldeveloper.org/blog/b/openxmldeveloper/archive/2009/08/06/7293.aspx):

```
// Fluent UI customisation to add a single button to the PowerPoint ribbon //
// Written by Jamie Garroch of YOUpresent Ltd. http://youpresent.co.uk //
<customUI xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/2009/07/customui">
  <ribbon>
    <tabs>
      <tab id="tabMyTab" label="My Tab">
        <group id="grpMyGroup" label="My Group">
          <button id="btnMyButton" label="My Button" onAction="MyMacro"/>
        </group>
      </tab>
    </tabs>
  </ribbon>
</customUI>
```

...then close the file in the CustomUI Editor and reopen in PowerPoint. Then add your macro:

```
' PowerPoint macro to change the fill colour of a single selected shape
' Written by Jamie Garroch of YOUpresent Ltd. http://youpresent.co.uk
Public Sub MyMacro(control As IRibbonControl)
  With ActiveWindow.Selection
    If .Type = ppSelectionShapes Then
      If .ShapeRange.Count = 1 Then
        If .ShapeRange.Type = msoAutoShape Then
          .ShapeRange.Fill.ForeColor.RGB = RGB(255, 0, 0)
         End If
      End If
    End If
  End With
End Sub
```

Now when you click **My Button** in your custom tab **My Tab**, if there is a single selected shape of type AutoShape on the slide in view then the fill colour will change to red.